# Flex Identify tool version 3 1085 error

Tags: arcgis-flex-api

I am building a flex web map app. I am using the Identify tool version 3, [here](http://www.arcgis.com/home/item.html?id=39cf66d58c234279ba728c50461a1a89#). Below is the syntax I am using, based on the PDF help file. It, however, gives a 1085 error. Does anyone know if I am using the correct syntax?

```
<layers onlythese="true">
    <layer>
        <name>Australia offices</name>
        <fields>
            <field name="Address" />
                            <field name="City" />
                            <field name="State" />
                            <field name="Postcode" />
                    </fields>
        <links>
            <link includeinresults="false" field="" alias="" tooltip=""/> 
                <linkprefix></linkprefix>
                <linksuffix></linksuffix>
                <iconfield></iconfield>
                <iconprefix></iconprefix>
                <iconsuffix></iconsuffix>
            </link>
        </links>
        <zoomscale>15000</zoomscale>
        <forcescale>true</forcescale>
             </layer>
             <layer>
                    <name>QLD rail</name>
        <fields>
            <field name="FNAME" alias="Name"/>
                            <field name="ELECTRIFIE" alias="Electrified"/>
                    </fields>
        <links>
            <link includeinresults="false" field="" alias="" tooltip=""/> 
                <linkprefix></linkprefix>
                <linksuffix></linksuffix>
                <iconfield></iconfield>
                <iconprefix></iconprefix>
                <iconsuffix></iconsuffix>
            </link>
        </links>
        <zoomscale>15000</zoomscale>
        <forcescale>true</forcescale>
    </layer>
</layers>
```

Comment: Did you try including the shape field in your fields collection?

Comment: Hi Kirk - actually this question can be deleted as there as a syntax error elsewhere in the widget config. I have more problems with this widget though and may ask more questions if I can't get any answers from the developer.

Comment: If you feel this question should be deleted, please do so.